# Why do the values of fields change after choosing unique identifer , SDE

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, enterprise-geodatabase, unique-id, sdelayer

I have a large dataset table from an SDE (SDE is the term my company uses to refer to this .under its properties (Oracle Enterprise Geodatabase).

When initiated adding the table dataset to my ArcMap. I do this by using the ArcCatalog and dragging and dropping the table into my map.

I am then prompted to set a Identifier 
This is using ArcGIS 10.3

As detailed here

http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/databases/choose-unique-identifier.htm

So this was not an issue. But I noticed that when I pulled SDE and checked the records in the attribute table.

The field I picked for the Unique Id is retained. But some other fields that were Long Int with values like 456677 have no changed to -4. If I pick this fields as the Unique Identifier. Then there values will be fine. But it will change the others. I was wondering if anyone has seen or knows what might be the root of this issue

The Data location of the SDE is locked down, so there is not much I can do to analyze it.

Comment: SDE no longer exists. Please [edit] the question to specify the database product and version in which the data resides, the exact version of ArcGIS in use, whether an enterprise geodatabase has been enabled (and if  so, what version was used), and the exact table definition. Of particular concern is whether your datatypes are supported by ArcGIS. The meaning of "pulled SDE" is unclear.

Comment: You still haven't provided the version of Oracle, whether an enterprise geodatabase is present, or the exact table definition. It you can access the data, it's not so "locked down" that you can't describe the table layout. Without this information, we can't begin to guess what might be going on.